# Android drawArc not drawing properly

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw

I'm working on some kind of circular view where the Arc is drawn on every onDraw() call. Whole onDraw method looks like this

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float beg = 0;
    float end;
    if (items != null && items.size() > 0 && getSum() != 0)
        for (Map.Entry<Object, ItemDescriptor> item : items.entrySet()) {
            end = (item.getValue().getScore() / getSum()) * 360;
            Log.d("jano", "drawing from " + beg + " to " + (beg + end));
            canvas.drawArc(mBounds, beg, end, false, item.getValue().getPaint());
            beg += end;
        }
    else {
        canvas.drawArc(mBounds, beg, 360, false, defalutPaint);
    }
}
```

Paint for drawing:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setStrokeWidth(outerWidth);
```

ItemDescriptor holds score based on which i can compute how to display circle (composed of some Arcs). Log output is always OK, but Arcs are most of time but not always correct. For example see green part on image below.

Can somebody of you give me some inspiration how to display it always correct? Whole project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/VizGhar/Android-CircularView/tree/develop) as Android Studio poject

[image: Circular View Arc error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I'm sorry, it just looks like the Genymotion not displaying this correctly. Real device and Android emulator displays the view without errors.